# Lifted corner effect in Powerpoint

Tags: 3d, shadows, microsoft-powerpoint

How to create a lifted corner effect on a box in Powerpoint?

I want to achieve the "effect 2" result [as in this link](https://paulund.co.uk/learn-css-box-shadow).

Comment: Do you have access to any other software for creating images (photoshop?) or does this have to be done in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scriptmasters probably would write it in Sanskrit, but the rest of us must try something simpler. Here's one possiblity:

[image]

1. Draw a curve with the paper color. Add a shadow effect to it
2. Send the curve to the background

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a rectangle.
2. Use the ["edit points" function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-shapes-to-create-a-custom-shape-2c9ce121-7b28-46ed-aec9-eae20cdddb15) to lift the edges.
3. Mess around with the drop shadow of the object or literally place a second objet beneath it, giving it an opacity.

Comment: Follow the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: Please don't rely on a link in your answers. Always give at least a synopsis of the technique used in the content you link to. That way, your answer is still relevant in case the link breaks later. Link rot is rampant, and thus answers relying on links often get downvoted here. Thanks for understanding!